# Java debugging doesn't work on Azure VMs?

Tags: java, tomcat

I usually deploy my Tomcat/Java projects on AWS. I am very familiar with the process for opening a port for remote debugging. I usually use port 8000.

I know that you need to set -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp options when starting Java, and that the target port must not be blocked by a firewall.

Recently a customer requested we use Azure VMs instead of AWS, so I set one up. I made sure to open the correct port, and set up the correct Java options, and I can see from the Tomcat logs that they have been recognized.

Nevertheless, all attempts to attach to the remote debugger fail with a timeout message, as if there is nobody listening.

Why doesn't this work? What could I possibly have overlooked?

Comment: Quick note: if "nobody is listening" then this fact is usually propagated via ICMP (or TCP_RST) and you should see "connection refused" immediately. If you got "connection timeout" it seems to me like firewall is dropping incoming TCP_SYN. Make sure no firewall is doing so on OS-Level (as you mentioned that you configured AWS security policy to allow it)

Comment: Yeah I was going to suggest checking fire wall settings too, either on the physical machine, or on the VM.  It could be any device between your workstation and the VM could be blocking those ports too, so any router or proxy on the customer side could be set to reject packets.  Traceroute might help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't an issue with the firewall or anything else at the OS level. It's due to a subtle change in the JVM itself.

Previously, the expression "address=8000" meant "listen on all interfaces to port 8000". They changed it to mean, "listen on localhost to port 8000". This effectively means that "remote" debugging is only possible if the client is on the same computer.

To fix it, you have to either specify "address=[ipaddress]:8000" or use the special syntax "address=*:8000", which reproduces the old behavior of listening on all interfaces.

Frank